# My system is fetching data from a wrong table

Tags: php, sql, fetch

Instead of getting data from the `DOC_PROGRESS` table, it keeps on fetching data from the `DOCUMENT` TABLE. I need data from both tables but I think I'm doing it wrong. My query is below, by the way. Help me please.

```
("SELECT * FROM document AS dd JOIN doc_progress AS dp ON dd.p_id = dp.p_id WHERE (dd.p_id = '".$_SESSION['currentUser']."') AND (dp.progress = 'Read')");
```

```html
<?php
$select1 = "SELECT * FROM doc_progress AS dp JOIN document AS dd ON dd.p_id = dp.p_id WHERE (dd.p_id = '".$_SESSION['currentUser']."') AND (dp.progress = 'Unread')";
$sql= mysql_query($select1) or die (mysql_error());
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>

<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php echo $row2['date_created'] ?></td>

    <td><a href=""><?php 
    echo "<b>" . $row2['doc_title']. "</b>"; ?></a></td>

    <td> <?php 
    echo $row2['status'] ?></td>

    <td> <?php
    echo $row2['progress']; ?></td>

    <td> <?php echo $row2['time_created']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `DOCUMENT` table in FROM statement if you want to select data from DOC_PROGRESS ?

Try this:

```php
'SELECT DP.* 
FROM doc_progress DP
INNER JOIN document DOC ON DOC.p_id = DP.p_id
WHERE 
    DOC.p_id = ' . $_SESSION['currentUser'] . 'AND
    DP.progress = \'Read\'';
```

Comment: I did but it still displays the same output. Thanks for the help anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
("SELECT DD.*, DP.* FROM document DD INNER JOIN doc_progress DP ON DD.p_id = DP.p_id WHERE DD.p_id = '".$_SESSION['currentUser']."' AND DP.progress = 'Read'");
```

Comment: I did but it still displays the same output. Thanks for the help anyway. :)

Comment: can you put the screenshot tables?

Comment: I cannot. My 'reputation' is not enough to post pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your query asks for the columns you want from the database. You currently have;

```
SELECT * FROM document
```

so that's what you're getting.

To select all columns from the joined tables, you can use;

```
SELECT * FROM document, doc_progress
```

but you might be better to select specific columns, such as;

```
SELECT document.colname1, document.colname2, doc_progress.colname FROM document
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did but it still displays the same output. Thanks for the help anyway. :)